# How can I set the visibility for a xml element inside a fragment created via pager adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have this activity that instantiates 5 different fragments that represents passengers and add them to a view pager in tabs. Each of those inflates the same xml file. What I want to do is be able to set the visibility for some of the xml fields in each of the fragments according to the type of passenger. I identify the type of passenger based on the tab name.

E.g: The field 'etDataNasc' must only appear if the passenger is of type 'INF'.

When I instantiate the fragments, I put them in a fragments array and check if the correspondent tab name has the conditions I want (Have 'INF' at the end). If so, I want to access the etDataNasc field from that fragment and set its visibility to VISIBLE, otherwise it has to be INVISIBLE.

I did some research here on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that helped me specifically. Based on some answers for similar issues, I tried inflating the layout inside the newInstance method but when try to set its visibility on my activity it still shows the field on every passenger!

Sorry for the long question, but any help would be deeply appreciated.

Here is my code for the Activity (the relevant parts to my problem):

```
public class DadosPassageirosActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerPassageirosAdapter pagerAdapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[];
private int nTitlesPassageiros = 1;

public int nAdultos, nCriancas, nBebes, nPassageiros;
private Passageiro[] passageirosArray;
private int arrayControl = 0;

private DrawerLayout filtrosDrawerLayout;
private ListView drawerList;

public DadosPassageirosFragment[] passageiroFragment;

public Button btnProsseguir;

static boolean isInf;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados_passageiros);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    nAdultos = intent.getExtras().getInt("nAdultos");
    nCriancas = intent.getExtras().getInt("nCriancas");
    nBebes = intent.getExtras().getInt("nBebes");
    nPassageiros = intent.getExtras().getInt("nPassageiros");
    passageirosArray = new Passageiro[nPassageiros];
    passageiroFragment = new DadosPassageirosFragment[nPassageiros];

    Titles = new CharSequence[nPassageiros];

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<nPassageiros; i++){
        Titles[i] = nTitlesPassageiros + "° Passageiro" + " (ADT)";
        nTitlesPassageiros +=1;
    }

    if (nCriancas > 0){
        for (i=nCriancas; i>0; i--){
            Titles[(Titles.length-i)-nBebes] = Titles[(Titles.length-i)-nBebes].subSequence(0,13) + " (CHD)";
        }
    }

    if (nBebes >0){
        for (i=nBebes; i>0; i--){
            Titles[Titles.length-i] = Titles[Titles.length-i].subSequence(0,13) + " (INF)";
        }
    }


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    pagerAdapter =  new ViewPagerPassageirosAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,nPassageiros, this);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    for (i=0; i<nPassageiros; i++){
        passageiroFragment[i] = (DadosPassageirosFragment)pagerAdapter.getItem(i);
        getTabName(i);
    }
}

public void getTabName(int pos){
    CharSequence title = pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(pos);
    if (title.subSequence(title.length()-4, title.length()-1).equals("INF")){
            passageiroFragment[pos].etDataNasc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        passageiroFragment[pos].etDataNasc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerPassageirosAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

Context mContext;

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerPassageirosAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb, Context c) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
    this.mContext = c;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    DadosPassageirosFragment tab = DadosPassageirosFragment.newInstance(this.mContext);
    return tab;

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
}
```

And here is the fragment itself with the Instance method:

```
public class DadosPassageirosFragment extends Fragment {


static EditText etNome, etSobrenome, etEmail;
TextView aviso;
public EditText etDataNasc;

DadosPassageirosActivity dadosPassageiros;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form_passageiro, container, false);

    dadosPassageiros = (DadosPassageirosActivity)getActivity();

    etNome = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.formPassageirosNome);
    //etSobrenome = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.formPassageirosSobrenome);
    //etEmail = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.formPassageirosEmail);
    etDataNasc = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.formPassageirosDataNasc);

    return v;
}

public static DadosPassageirosFragment newInstance(Context c){
    DadosPassageirosFragment f = new DadosPassageirosFragment();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form_passageiro, null, false);

    f.etDataNasc = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.formPassageirosDataNasc);
    return f;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a long solution so ask me if you dont understand something..
on the `DadosPassageirosFragment` add a boolean that decides if the object should be visible..

```
boolean isVisible;
```

on the main Activity create all the Fragments and update the isVisible var according to your needs..

send all the fragments to the Adapter dont create them inside the Fragment just return the correct according to the selected poistion.

```
public ViewPagerPassageirosAdapter(`DadosPassageirosFragment[] fragments`...
```

when the system will built each Fragment it will check the isVisible var and shows/hide this EditText

use `onStart()` function to VISIBLE/INVISIBLE the EditText

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you walk me through the steps to add the fragments to the activity? I think I understand your solution, but I'm having trouble testing it.

I tried using the fragment manager, but I don't know which container I should add the fragment...

`for (i=0; i<nPassageiros; i++) {
            DadosPassageirosFragment frag = new DadosPassageirosFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(frag, R.id.pager, "tag");
        }`

Comment: the Adapter will do that for you thats why you send the FragmentManager to the Adapter just create them and place them inside the array and send the array to the Adapter

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I just can't seem to get a grasp of how Fragments work on Android, but you somehow made it clearer. Would you mind explaining for me why my previous code wasn't working?

My idea in it was to get a reference of the instance of each fragment and update the visibility of the EditText from my activity.

Comment: when you create a new fragment its call the onCreateView but you didnt set any condition to change EditText visiblity.. so my suggestion was creating all Fragments in advnace set the condition and let the adapter handle the "fragment drawing"